# How can I achieve a "painted" effect in my scene in blender?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I would like to model some rooms and offices and achieve this sort of look when in done:

[image]

[image]

Im fine with modelling, but how can i go by in getting it to look like the style on these images? Is there a way to add a painted effect in blender to objects or even to the whole render? Or should I consider getting this look in post production in another program by applying effects?

Comment: not sure, but have a look at this: https://studiollb.wordpress.com/2013/01/05/ink-watercolor-effects-in-blender/

Answer (score 1):

The filters in *Photoshop* are your best bet. *Gimp* or *Krita* which are both free might also have such effects, but looking at the *Blender* compositon nodes i couldn't find any solutions. One thing that can be done in *Blender* are the lines using *Freestyle*. This will have the edges of all models show up and there are many advanced features regarding to this.